# Index of object equal to string

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

If I have an array of strings, can I reliably test if it contains a given string with `NSArray containsObject` - or should I loop through and test isEqualToString on each object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`containsObject:` uses `isEqual:`, which is reliable and tests for equality, i.e., if the object in the array and the parameter are really equal. It might actually call `isEqualToString:` under the hood.

Comment: and checks the hash first (which is a lot faster than isEqual) to quickly determine if two objects are *not* equal

Comment: If you're going to do a lot of `containsObject:` you might want to use set or dictionary instead. They are significantly faster at this operation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use containsObject method as well which is internally calls isequal method only.